# How can I reference objects with keys that have dots in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var ageRanges;
ageRanges = {
  '18.20': 0,
  '21.24': 0,
  '25.34': 0,
  '35.44': 0,
  '45.54': 0,
  '55.64': 0,
  '65+': 0
};
```

I want to access `ageRanges.'18.20'`, but that gives me an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null` - so what's the proper way to access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use it this way:

```
ageRanges['18.20']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ageRanges['18.20']` to access the property. This is one of two ways to access JavaScript object properties. The alternative and recommended way is dot-notation, which fails in this instance due to the period character in your property names.

Answer (score 3):

```
ageRanges["18.20"];
```

Easy-peasy.

Answer (score 2):

use `ageRanges["18.20"];` to access